# Count characters in Java with NESTED-LOOPS

Tags: java

> Write a Java program that will use NESTED FOR-LOOPS to prompt the user for a string of characters, and then for each character in the string, count the number of identical characters to its right.
>
> The program should
>
> 1. Ask the user to enter a string of 1 to 25 characters.
>    If the length is less than 1 or greater than 25, an error message (“Invalid Input”) should be displayed, and the program should stop.
> 2. Examine each character in the string, from left to right (starting at index 0).
>
> For each character, count the number of identical characters to its right (i.e., with higher index) and display that character and the count.

I did this.But it can't work like this.

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        String x=scanner.nextLine();
        int count=0;
        String temp="";
        if(x.length()>25||x.length()<1){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        else{
         for(int i=0;i < x.length();i++){
            char c1=x.charAt(i);
            for(int j=i;j < x.length();j++){
                char c2=x.charAt(j);  
                if(c1==c2 && temp.indexOf(c1)==-1){
                    count=count+1;
                }
            }
            if(temp.indexOf(c1)==-1){
                temp=temp+c1;
                System.out.println(c1+": "+(count-1));
            }
            count=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, first split the string into chars: `x.toCharArray()`, then iterate over the chars:

```java
char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    char current = chars[i];
    // see below
}
```

Then, just iterate over the string again, from `i+1` (+1 because we already checked the char at `i`), and compare:

```java
char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    char current = chars[i];
    int foundSimilar = 0;
    for(int ii = i+1; ii < chars.length; ii++) {
        char thatChar = chars[ii];
        if (thatChar == current) foundSimilar++;
    }
    // then just print out how many chars we found
    System.out.println(current + ": " + foundSimilar);
}
```

As you can see, this yields the same output as on the image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you comparing the same character, as i == j.

```
for(int j=i;j < x.length();j++){
                char c2=x.charAt(j);
```

You can start j from i+1.